# How kafka identifies consumers in a group uniquely

Tags: apache-kafka

I have multiple consumers in a group. How does kafka identify each consumer to be different and map it to partition.

Or - What is the unique key used to identify a consumer in the group

Comment: Hi, if you are satisfied with the answer, could you please consider to accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kafka generates a random consumer id with a format like

```
<client.id>-<uuid>
```

You can see this running a new console consumer in a group.

```
$ ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka-1:9092 --consumer-property group.id=group1 -consumer-property client.id=myClient --topic topic1
```

and, while the consumer is running, executing the command line kafka-consumer-groups.sh to describe that group. Take a look at the CONSUMER-ID column.

```
$ ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka-1:9092 --describe --group group1
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).


TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
topic1                         0          0               0               0          myClient-e137f762-e550-4c8e-96d9-8f7f725e2c6d     /127.0.0.1                     myClient
```

Relevant Kafka code as of 0.10.2.1 looks like this:

```
val memberId = clientId + "-" + group.generateMemberIdSuffix
```

where

```
def generateMemberIdSuffix = UUID.randomUUID().toString
```